# Finding parent of checked out version in ClearCase

Tags: bash, clearcase

I want to find the parent of a checked out file in ClearCase from a Bash script. For example, if I type `ct ls` I get this:

```
$ ct ls some_file
some_file@@/main/some/branch/CHECKEDOUT from some_file@@/main/some/branch/6   Rule: CHECKEDOUT
```

I want to find the parent version (`some_file@@/main/some/branch/6`) from a script. Sure I can use awk or similar text processing tools, but I think that's a very ugly solution, and can easily break for more exotic file names (for example if it has spaces or the string "from" in it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "`%PSn`" format of [`fmt_ccase`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm) (cleartool describe)

```
 cleartool describe -fmt "%PSn" some_file@@/main/some/branch/CHECKEDOUT

 %PSn
```

> **Predecessor Short name**:
>   For a version, a short form of the predecessor version's version ID: `branch-pathname/version-number`.
>   For other objects, the null string.

Note that for `@@/main/0` (which [all elements, files or directories, have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309333/why-i-only-get-a-clearcase-version-0/5309714#5309714)), it will also return a null string.

---

The [OP petersohn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/294813/petersohn) [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739619/finding-parent-of-checked-out-version-in-clearcase/13739872#comment18924036_13739872) that it is similar to:

```
cleartool describe -short -pred some_file@@/main/some/branch/CHECKEDOUT
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I found out that `cleartool describe -short -pred some_file@@/main/some/branch/CHECKEDOUT` works just as well. There is also a lot of useful stuff here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447178/script-to-get-a-files-version-in-clearcase

Comment: @petersohn Interesting. I have including your command in the answer for more visibility.